Python 312 Windows 11 pandas.read_html() ssl fail with urllib.error.URLError CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED on common sites like wikipedia
Example:
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_films');

**Error: **
raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1000)>
Description:
Tried accessing several sites with Python using pandas, request and selenium all give
SSL type errors. As the same windows user I can browse these sites manually in any Windows browser I have tried. Have also checked recent similar issues for answers without luck.
Anyone else run into this?

What version of ca-certificates is your environment using?  It looks like your CA cert bundle is old.

Thanks for the feedback James! I will continue looking into that. Everything set for default and Windows Security is uptodate and nothing else appears to have any issues. Also the user has admin rights. Need to track down which version Python is having problems with.

Should be closed. Seems I was very unlucky as to my choice of my different sites. Apparently  [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1000) was coming from the server side. In my example this was https://en.wikipedia.org on my side my *.pem file was good.
